# What TCP segment retransmission rate indicates something bad?

Tags: networking, tcp, netstat

For a long time, I’ve suspected there’s a problem with my home network. (Basic AT&T gateway/router with residential fiber).  I’m running Windows Performance Manager and monitoring the TCP segments retransmitted per second.  I monitored for about an hour, and the rate was on average about 0.6. Does this rate indicate a problem?  I read that a rate persistently above 0.1 is usually a sign that there’s a problem, but I’ve only found 1 website that prescribes this (arbitrary) limit.  By comparison, my computer at work (independent and reliable network) exhibited an average rate of about 0.02.

Does an average rate of 0.6 indicate a problem? I simply have no idea what to expect.

Comment: Just to be clear, what units are we talking about here? Is that 0.6 retransmits per second? How does that work out as percentage of transmitted segments? For example, if you were doing a TCP upload that was keeping a 1Gbps AT&T GPON residential fiber link saturated, that would be over 81,000 full-size segments per second, so a retransmit rate of 0.6 per second works out to a tiny fraction of the transmissions. But if you were barely ever transmitting any TCP segments during the time your were monitoring, then a retransmit rate of 0.6 pps could be a large percentage of the total transmissions.

Comment: Also note that many of the most popular TCP congestion control algorithms intentionally induce packet loss and retransmission. They do it to make sure they're maximizing performance. They transmit faster and faster until they detect loss and have to do a retransmit; when they detect loss they consider it a sign of congestion of back off a little, and then ramp the speed back up until they see loss again. That way they know they're "bumping their head on the ceiling" of performance. So *some* retransmission is a sign of everything going *right*.